る/base verb and た　are just a another version of ている　in a relative clause?
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3362/65948
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3364/65948
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43875/65948
And many others say that it doesn’t matter what tense is modifying a noun, ている and た mean the same thing if 1)they are modifying a noun and 2)the verb itself expresses a state and not the English -ing.
That’s all fine and well until I saw this post: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73683/65948
I’ve never seen a dictionary form being changeable with the た　form in a relative clause. This wrecked my existing knowledge that only た　and ている can be changed without their meanings changing. I was so confused about it.
That’s when I saw these posts: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14553/65948
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14273/6594
It all makes sense now, る　ている　た　means the exact same thing. It all basically boils down to this:
た=ている=る　they all have the same meaning as ている and た and る　are just a disguised version of it
But the two rules that only this can happen is

it has to be in a relative clause but more importantly
the verb has too be a stative verb to begin with.

If these two are fulfilled, then it doesn’t matter what you choose cause they all mean the same thing. At the end of the day they only have slight difference that being:

base verb is more likely to be seen in formal/polite places like in a story or newspaper etc and thus have a more polite feeling to it and because it’s uses the base form of the verb, it pulls you into the time period that happens, like you’re actually there of when that thing happens, making it more “real time action” https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43622/65948
And because of this link, this means that this is the historical present, for so long I’ve been so stumped about it until this came and clears everything for me. Your both using the more polite version of ている (る/base verb) and also you’re using historical present at the same time. A double combo that I didn’t see coming.

ている　being used in colloquial/day to day places so that’s why the base verb is preferred in formal scenarios. So you should use it with friends but not in a speech or something like that. It also focuses on more of the state itself than the verb being done

た can be used in formal or informal scenarios but it doesn’t have the same kind of pulling that る/base verb has, it just tells you about it and doesn’t give you the “real time action” that it has. And this usually has more of a nuance that the verb has been done instead of saying what the state is like right now.


For a demonstration, I’m going to take this "太ってる猫" vs "太った猫"
太ってる猫=太った猫=太る猫
They all mean the exact same grammatically. Cause at the end of the day, た　and る/base verb are all just a different version of ている with slight nuance. They are all interchangeable.
But that just leaves me with this question, is this answer credible? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11976/65948
By credible I mean his method of determining when a verb can be interchangeable with た　and ている cause there are two explanation that he gave and I’m not quite sure that he knows what he’s talking about. The first one is:

shouldn’t かぶる be in its causative form like one of the comments says
And number two:

Shouldn’t this be 食べられた? 食べたケーキ means “A cake that ate(something)” like literally a sentient cake that ate something? Even if you don’t thing that’s the case then the it still wouldn’t make sense cause the cake still isn’t getting eaten by someone cause 食べた is just ate and not got eaten, 食べられたケーキ　means “a cake that got eaten (by someone)” so I really hope someone actually comes out and clears it up cause I still have no idea how or when a verb can be interchangeable with た　and ている. My guess is that it must have to do with the verb being stative in the first place or not.
And also regarding his explanation on the dictionary form does in a relative clause, he says it usually takes the future reading and habitual reading but doesn’t say anything about it being used in formal scenarios, like this post says, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14553/65948
So I might need someone to fact check on it, or maybe both can be accepted cause at the end of the day context matters the most.

I may try and write an answer later, but just for clarity here: none of the verb forms you've given here are universally interchangeable when used in relative clauses. The links to questions all show specific cases where they are interchangeable, and there are many of those, but it is certainly not the case (nor do I think anyone is saying that) they are always interchangeable. It's very context dependent

Then I would really need your help on this one cause for the last couple of days I’ve been so weirded out on the fact that a base verb is taking the place of ている and it’s been driving me crazy but seeing that base verb is usually used in formal situations, that it makes so much sense now. If they truly aren’t ている changed into base verb just for the extra politeness and the “live” feeling than I truly have no idea why it’s used

Also why do i think like this is because I’ve been watching some explainer videos and one particular channels loves using base verb in places that makes no sense, but not just that, they leave out a crucial detail that for a Japanese person may not affect them too much but for learners like me, it’s so confusing. Also one of the reasons why I believe they are using ている as base verb is to make it more educational-like but to be honest I’m 100 percent sure they’re just doing it so they can fit the subtitles on one row instead of two rows.

食べたケーキ means “A cake that ate(something)” Technically it could mean that, but "a cake that [sb] ate" (≈ a cake that was eaten) is also a possible interpretation, and obviously the most realistic/common one. The noun modified by a relative clause doesn't have to be the subject of the clause's verb; it can have basically any sort of relationship with it, to be determined only by context and common sense. Consider also 読んだ本 "book [I] read" (relativised version of 本を読んだ), not "book that read" — or 遊んだ公園 "park where [I/they/someone] played" (→ 公園で遊んだ), not "park that played".

shouldn’t かぶる be in its causative form like one of the comments says かぶせる is not the causative of かぶる (which would be かぶらせる instead); it's another, separate verb that means "to put [on sb's head]" (I think かぶらせる would mean "to make [sb] wear [sth] on their head" by comparison). Note, aguijonazo calls it a causative "verb" (because it's a causative/transitive-y sort of counterpart to かぶる), not the causative form of かぶる. Consider also a verb like 乗せる (vs. 乗る). I guess Darius just made a usage error here because かぶる also means "to put on [one's head]".

I originally didn't want to answer this because it's a bit long and I don't feel confident to provide a complete answer, but no one else is so I'll provide a partial one to the best of my abilities.
Firstly, the common similarity between “〜ている” and “〜た”　has nothing to do with relative clauses and exists everywhere. The same exists in English too. “I have eaten.” and “I ate.” have fairly interchangeable meaning, but one focuses on the result in the now, and the other on the action in the past that caused said result. “〜ている” at it's core meaning indicates a monotonous span of time rather a point. This is frequently the result of the verb, such as say in “温まっている” but may also be, if the verb be monotonous in it's own right such as “食べる” mark the currently ongoing action such that “食べている” can both mean “has eaten" and “is eating” depending on context because “eating” unlike warming up is a monotonous action without a clear endpoint where something is transformed. Outside of relative clauses “太った” means “I got fat.” and “太っている” means “I have gotten fat.” or “I am fat.”, even in English, these two have nigh-identical meaning.
Now, as for relative clauses. There are two important things to unpack: first is that Japanese relative clauses have relative tense, not absolute tense like in English. Their tense is relative to the main clause they're embedded in, as such, in Japanese we say “食べている人を見た。” to mean “I saw someone who was eating.”, namely, at the time of seeing, that person was currently eating, so the past form is not used. If it were, it meant one saw someone who was already done eating, and had eaten in the past relative to seeing, as in “I saw someone who was eating before I saw him.”, if you will. This also means that past forms in relative clauses can be used for a future event, as in “食べたあと寝るつもりだ。” as in “I plan to go to bed after I have eaten.”, even though the “食べた” lies in the future relative to speaking, it is relative in the past to the planned time of going to bed, so the past tense is used.
The second thing to unpack with regards to relative clauses is that indeed for many verbs, the plain form seems to be interchangeable with the “〜ている” form. I can't give a very confident answer to what subset this exactly is. It seems to be pretty much exactly the subset that uses the “〜ている”　form to mark a resultant state, but I'm not entirely sure of that either. As an example I can use “それを知る人と話していた。” to mean “I was talking to someone who knew that.”. This is essentially interchangeable with “知っている” yes and this applies only to relative clauses. “それを知る” does not mean “I know this.” but “I will learn of this.” and we must outside of a relative clause use “それを知っている。” or “それを知った。” which means “I have learned of this.” As far as I know “パンを食べる人と話していた。” does not mean “I was talking to someone who was eating bread.”, but I might be wrong about this. Again, I'm providing an incomplete answer here simply because no one else is.

So for a verb that can both express the state of a thing, which is preferred in a relative clause? た or ている? Is it the same as the English example you gave me about when we use “I ate” and “I’ve eaten”? If a た is used in relative clause rather than ている, does that mean that it expresses that the verb happened more than its state? Is ている in a relative clause talking more about the state of the thing?

@JackyPlays yes, if the verb be a state change yes. Typically the verb itself expresses the transition of achieving that change and it, as said, doesn't have much to do with relative clauses. “寝る” is commonly explained as to mean “to sleep”, but it actually means “to go to sleep”, “寝ている” means sleeping. And “He went to sleep.” and “He is sleeping” are very similar, are they not?.
